# How to store a long value in java dynamically?

Tags: java

I was solving a problem on a competitive coding website in java. My code for the problem is:

```
long arr[]=new long[1000001];
for(int i=2;i<=1000000;i++)
{
    arr[i]=arr[i-1]+(i*(i-1));
}
int Test = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
for (int i = 0; i < Test; i++) {
    int num=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println(arr[num]);
}
```

Input

3

1

2

3

4

It is showing correct output as:

0

2

8

20

But when the input is like:

3

10000

100000

1000000

It is showing as:

333333330000

18108503577376

16881588911936

but the output should be:

333333330000

333333333300000

333333333333000000

the last two is wrong.I tried using BigInteger but the time gets exceeded.
However I solved it in python 2.7:

```
a=[]
a.append(0)
a.append(0)
for i in range(2,1000001):
    a.append(a[i-1]+(i*(i-1)));
t=input()
while t:
    t-=1
    print a[input()]
```

Input:

Input

3

10000

100000

1000000

Output

333333330000

333333333300000

333333333333000000

Someone please help me how to solve this in Java.
Why is it not showing correct output even if the answer fits into a long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing most of your calculation with **`int`s**, not `long`s:

```
arr[i]=arr[i-1]+(i*(i-1));
//              ^^^^^^^^^------ All of this is with `int`s
```

So it overflows the `int` range before being converted to a `long` when you add it to `arr[i-1]`.

To avoid overflow, you'll want to cast so you're working with `long`s earlier:

```
arr[i]=arr[i-1]+((long)i*(i-1));
//               ^^^^^^
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/1LvWoO)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. But why is arr[i]=arr[i-1]+(long)(i*(i-1)); not working.

Comment: @Processor: Because `i*(i-1)` is processed with `int` values, and overflows. You're casting the *result* of `i*(i-1)`, by which time overflow has already occurred.

Comment: Ok  now I understand.